# Is there an official list of Fabuland animal characters?

Tags: minifigure-identification, fabuland

I found in an old box these animal characters.

They are all LEGO original (the logo is present on all their parts).

They are 25, maybe 30, years old. I think is the Fabuland series. I wonder if there is any way to discover how many they were and if there is any way to complete the collection.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Brickset has a [list of 89 Fabuland figures](https://brickset.com/minifigs/category-Fabuland/page-2).
- Bricklink has a [list of 93 Fabuland figures](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&catString=153&catType=M), these include
  variations in accessories.
- Fabuland.net states there are 142 characters in 80 variations and has
  a [full list of characters](http://www.fabuland.net/pages/inventory/figpic.html) including which sets they were sold
  with.

If you were to collect one of every animal type (excluding colour variations) you would at the very least need 20 Fabuland Figures:

- Bear/Panda/Racoon
- Bird
- Bunny
- Cat
- Cow
- Crocodile
- Bulldog
- Dog
- Poodle
- Elephant
- Fox
- Goat
- Hippo
- Horse
- Lamb
- Lion
- Mouse
- Monkey
- Pig
- Walrus

There are variations between figures in the copyright markings on the back of the legs, face printing between similar figures. In addition to the standard figures there are [72 variations of Fabuland Keychains](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=2&catString=334.153&catType=G).

Comment: Wow. That's great. I didn't know Fabuland.net existed.

Comment: Fabuland.net seems the most completed one. Your answer is the best one. Thank you!

Comment: bear, panda and racoon are really just color variations, whereas the dogs are actually different shapes. for the smallest complete set, i'd rather go with different shapes, and throw the bears into one category.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how official of a list you are looking for, but there are 93 Fabuland minifigs [listed on Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?v=2&pg=1&catLike=W&catType=M&catID=153):

[image: Bricklink screenshot]

Here's the full list from there:

```
fab1a   Fabuland Figure Bear 1
fab1c   Fabuland Figure Bear 2
fab1b   Fabuland Figure Bear 3
Fab2k   Fabuland Figure Bulldog 1
fab2e (Inv)     Fabuland Figure Bulldog 1 with Fire Helmet
fab2a (Inv)     Fabuland Figure Bulldog 1 with Police Hat
fab2b   Fabuland Figure Bulldog 2 with Police Hat
fab2d   Fabuland Figure Bulldog 3
fab2c (Inv)     Fabuland Figure Bulldog 3 with Police Hat
fab2j   Fabuland Figure Bulldog 3 with Police Hat and Post Pattern
fab2l   Fabuland Figure Bulldog 6
fab2g (Inv)     Fabuland Figure Bulldog 6 with Fire Helmet
fab2f   Fabuland Figure Bulldog 7 with Fire Helmet
fab2h   Fabuland Figure Bulldog 8 with Fire Helmet
fab2i   Fabuland Figure Bulldog 9 with Fire Helmet
fab3a   Fabuland Figure Bunny 1
fab3b   Fabuland Figure Bunny 2
fab3c   Fabuland Figure Bunny 3
fab3d   Fabuland Figure Bunny 4 - Collar Pattern
Fab3e   Fabuland Figure Cat 1
fab3f   Fabuland Figure Cat 2
fab3g   Fabuland Figure Cat 3
fab3h   Fabuland Figure Cat 4
fab3i   Fabuland Figure Cat 5
fab4a   Fabuland Figure Cow
fab4b   Fabuland Figure Crocodile 1
fab4c   Fabuland Figure Crocodile 2
fab4d   Fabuland Figure Crow 1 with Aviator Helmet and Black Eyes
fab4h   Fabuland Figure Crow 1 with Aviator Helmet and White Eyes
fab4e   Fabuland Figure Crow 2
Fab4f   Fabuland Figure Crow 3 with Aviator Helmet
Fab4g   Fabuland Figure Dog
fab5a   Fabuland Figure Elephant 1
fab5b   Fabuland Figure Elephant 2
fab5c   Fabuland Figure Elephant 3
fab5d   Fabuland Figure Elephant 4 with Yellow Hat and Black Eyes
fab5i   Fabuland Figure Elephant 4 with Yellow Hat and White Eyes
fab5e   Fabuland Figure Fox 1
fab5f   Fabuland Figure Fox 2 with Yellow Hat
fab5g   Fabuland Figure Goat 1
fab5h   Fabuland Figure Goat 2
fab6e   Fabuland Figure Hippo 1
fab6f   Fabuland Figure Hippo 2 - Necklace Pattern
fab001BHP   Fabuland Figure Hippo 3 - LEGO Centre / Birkenhead Point Sydney Pattern
fab6a   Fabuland Figure Horse 1
fab6b   Fabuland Figure Horse 2
fab6c   Fabuland Figure Horse 3
fab6d   Fabuland Figure Horse 4
fab002BHP   Fabuland Figure Horse 5 - LEGO Centre / Birkenhead Point Sydney Pattern
fab7a   Fabuland Figure Lamb 1
 fab7b  Fabuland Figure Lamb 2
Fab7h   Fabuland Figure Lamb 3
fab7d   Fabuland Figure Lamb 4
fab7e   Fabuland Figure Lion 1
fab7f   Fabuland Figure Lion 2
fab7g   Fabuland Figure Lion 2 with White Hat
fab8a   Fabuland Figure Monkey 1 with Light Gray Hat
fab8b   Fabuland Figure Monkey 1 with Red Hat
fab8f   Fabuland Figure Monkey 2
fab8h   Fabuland Figure Monkey 3 with White Hat
fab8d   Fabuland Figure Monkey 4
fab8e   Fabuland Figure Monkey 5
fab8i   Fabuland Figure Monkey 6 with White Hat
fab8c   Fabuland Figure Monkey 7
fab8g   Fabuland Figure Monkey 8
fab9a   Fabuland Figure Mouse 1
fab9b   Fabuland Figure Mouse 2
fab9d   Fabuland Figure Mouse 3
fab9c   Fabuland Figure Mouse 4
fab9e   Fabuland Figure Mouse 4 with White Cap
fab9f   Fabuland Figure Mouse 6
fab9g   Fabuland Figure Mouse 7
fab10a  Fabuland Figure Panda 1
fab10b  Fabuland Figure Panda 2
fab10c  Fabuland Figure Parrot
fab11a  Fabuland Figure Pig 1
fab11b  Fabuland Figure Pig 2
fab11c  Fabuland Figure Pig 3
fab11d  Fabuland Figure Pig 4
fab11e  Fabuland Figure Pig 5
fab11f  Fabuland Figure Pig 6
fab11g  Fabuland Figure Pig 7
fab7c   Fabuland Figure Poodle
fab14a  Fabuland Figure Poodle with Black Eyes
fab14b  Fabuland Figure Poodle with White Eyes
fab12a  Fabuland Figure Raccoon 1
fab12b  Fabuland Figure Raccoon 2
fab12d  Fabuland Figure Raccoon 3
fab12h  Fabuland Figure Raccoon 4
fab12c  Fabuland Figure Raccoon 5
fab12f  Fabuland Figure Walrus 1
fab12e  Fabuland Figure Walrus 2
fab12g  Fabuland Figure Walrus 3 - Anchor Pattern
```

You can purchase these on Bricklink as well in order to complete your collection.

Answer (score 2):

The Fabuland figures and sets were produced between 1979 and 1989. According to the BrickLink Catalog - which has the most comprehensive list of LEGO minifigures ever released - there are 93 Fabuland characters. Some of these however are slight variations (i.e. same animal, different color torso/legs/arms). You can find the full list here: [List of LEGO Fabuland Figures](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&catString=153&sortBy=Y&sortAsc=A&catType=M)

While some of the Fabuland characters can still be found fairly easily, others are very rare. Also, as the figures are so old, it can be difficult to find them in good condition. As demonstrated by the crow in the last row of your picture, the facial printing didn't stand up well to regular play. The hip and arm joints can also get very loose if the figures were played with regularly.